# Twig error - varibale does not exist for Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I am passing query results to my twig view but it can't find that varibale.

It' Sonata Admin details view with multiple tabs.

Tamplate is renderig and when I pass a string it renders but when I try to call query builder with "getTransactions" it throws:

> Variable "card" does not exist.

Code:

```
 $card = $this->getCardTransactions();

    $showMapper->tab('Card transactions')
                    ->add('Data', 'date', array(
                        'template' => "@AdminTemplates/details.html.twig",
                        'card' => $card
                    ))
                    ->end()
                ->end()
```

And simple as that in my twig:

```
{% for c in card %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.title }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}#}
```

Comment: Is it "Data" or "data"? Should the letter case match?

Comment: I updated the answer. That part is fine it's just the tab name.  $card varibale throws an error. @MilanG

Comment: If the error is occuring when calling `getCardTransactions` then surely the error is situated over there and not in `twig`

Comment: It's not. When I dump() the fucntion it return all results. @DarkBee

Comment: Your (posted) twig template does not contain any variable called data?

Comment: Sorry for that. It's actually card variable. @DarkBee

Comment: Are you using the variable `card` inside a macro?

Comment: No, it's just like this. :/ @DarkBee