# twig variable won't pass - symfony sonata

Tags: twig, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, symfony-sonata

5 days have gone by, still no success!

I dumped the results of my card variable and it returns results.

But when I try to pass it trough varibale on my twig tamplate it throws:

> Variable "card" does not exist.

It's defined in SonataAdmin.

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{

    $card = $this->getCardTransactions(); // on dump(), it works

    $showMapper->tab('Cards')
                    ->add('Data', 'string', array(
                        'template' => "@AdminTemplates/sonata/details.html.twig",
                        'card' => $card
                    ))
                    ->end()
                ->end();
}
```

and in my twig;

```
 {% for c in card %}
      {{ c.id }}
  {% endfor %}
```

I think it has to do with SonataAdmin and how it handles this type of calls but I have read the documentation and searched online but still no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig error - varibale does not exist for Sonata Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183910/twig-error-varibale-does-not-exist-for-sonata-admin)

Comment: Why posting twice your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `field_description.options` object in your template to access your variable.

```php
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{

    $showMapper
        ->tab('Cards')
            ->add('Data', 'string', [
                'template' => "@AdminTemplates/sonata/details.html.twig",
                'card' => $this->getCardTransactions(),
            ])
        ->end();
}
```

```html
{# @AdminTemplates/sonata/details.html.twig #}
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{%- block field -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for card in field_description.options.cards %}
            {{ card.id }}
        {% else %}
            <p>No card</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock -%}
```